# Getting parameter in .Net through shell

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have built a program that calculates the size of file specified. I Now wants to pass the file path as a parameter to my program. I run the following command in cmd

```
fileSize.exe filepath
```

Now I want to call the parameter filePath in my .NET Program. I am a .NET newbie. In PHP we can do.

```
$filePath = $_GET['filepath'];
```

How can I do the similar thing with .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Use navigation of the left side for sub-topics.

Comment: In the reference link you have mention I can not find a way to name the parameter. Can I name the parameter in key=value form? and then call it in my program by its name.

Comment: No you can't. You will have to parse key value pairs yourself or use available 3rd party library: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=command+line+parser